# Javascript Validate alphanumeric with minimum text length

Tags: javascript, html, validation

This script is working properly to validate alphanumeric without spaces. But how will i also include that the minimum length should be at least 3 chars?

```
var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9']+$/;
// Check input
if (re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)) {
    // Style green
    document.getElementById(x).style.background = '#ccffcc';
    // Hide error prompt
    document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
    return true;
} else {
    // Style red
    document.getElementById(x).style.background = '#e35152';
    // Show error prompt
    document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9']{3,}$/;

.     (Zero or more items)
+     (One or more items)
{n}   (Exactly n items)
{n,m} (Between n and m items where n < m)
```

Comment: `\d` means digits, it is equivalent to `[0-9]`, and `\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Pay attention that `\w` includes underscore too.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `+` quantifier (which means one or more times) to `{3,}` (which means three or more times):

```
var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9']{3,}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an appropriate quantifier in your regular expression:

```
var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9']{3,}$/;
```

Or refactor your validation into its own function, which would be more maintainable:

```
var isValid = function(value) {
     var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9']+$/;
     if (!re.test(value))  { return false; }
     if (value.length < 3) { return false; }
     // further tests could go here
     return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the regexp to:

```
var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9']{3,}$/;
```

The quantifier `{min,max}` means from `min` to `max` repetitions. If you leave either of them out, it means that end is unlimited, so `{3,}` means at least 3.